# How to assign bean value to html:text in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

```
<bean:write scope="session" name="USERSESSION" property="userId" />

<html:text tabindex="1"  name="RequestForm" property="currentuser" value='<bean:write scope="session" name="USERSESSION" property="userId" />' readonly="true"/>
```

What are the other ways to assign Bean value to Html:text default value

Answer (score 2):

You can not combine `<bean>` tags with `<html>` tags.

Use `<bean:define>` to define a variable with an id and next use id with JSP EL to set the value to `<html:text>` tag.

Try the following:

```
<bean:define id="sessUserId" scope="session" name="USERSESSION" property="userId" />

<html:text tabindex="1"  name="RequestForm" property="currentuser" value='${sessUserId}' readonly="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
<jsp:useBean id="USERSESSION" scope="session" type="<DATA_TYPE>">
<html:text tabindex="1"  name="RequestForm" property="currentuser" value='<%=USERSESSION.getUserid()%>' readonly="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a taglib inside an attribute of another taglib. What you need to do, is set the variable in the page, then use it later.

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm for example.